# perceptron classification and R

Tags: r, perceptron

I have four points: a=(-0.5, -0.5) b=(-0.5, 0.5) c=(0.3, -0.5) d=(0.0, 1.0)

I need to classificate these points, first a,b and after c, d

The first step is to define the perceptron, but, What is the way to define a perceptron in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to show that you've done some homework ...

```
library(sos)
findFn("perceptron")
RSiteSearch("perceptron")  ## after running this, click on some buttons on the web page to expand the search
```

Search "perceptron" at http://rseek.org

Also search StackOverflow for `[r] perceptron`, although that doesn't get much; you might try `[r] neural net` too ...

Comment: Hello Ben. I am learning about neural network with AMORE package. This is the first time that I work with Neural Networks and I need some help. My problem is what is the best package to complete my classification? and the target function at the package? Thanks Ben